# Is it possible to restrict the number of items show in WeBlog tag cloud within Sitecore?

Tags: sitecore, weblog

I am using the [WeBlog](https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/WeBlog.aspx) module in Sitecore 7.1. After years of blog posts, the [tag cloud](https://github.com/WeTeam/WeBlog/wiki/Sidebar-Components) control now shows a huge list of all the tags which have ever been used in a post. Is it possible to restrict the number of tags which show or provide a minimum threshold for the number of times each tag needs to have been used?

I can't find any information in the documentation or within the Sitecore content editor, but I assume it must be a common problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I know there is no way of limiting the number of tags in the `TagCloud` sublayout out of the box.

However you can create your own `CustomTagManager` class, inherit from `Sitecore.Modules.WeBlog.Managers.TagManager` and override the implementation of the `GetAllTags()` method to get only first N tags.

When you have your `CustomTagManager`, just register it in `WeBlog.config` file instead of this line:

```cs
<setting name="WeBlog.Implementation.TagManager" value="Sitecore.Modules.WeBlog.Managers.TagManager"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it does this out of the box and by default it get's all the tags.

As WeBlog is open source and on Github you could fork your own version and modify it to your requirements.

Here's the part where the Tags are rendered in the side bar:

https://github.com/WeTeam/WeBlog/blob/3da28ffd1431bdec27fa0ef2775701807015c60f/Website/layouts/WeBlog/Sidebar/TagCloud.ascx.cs